# Update database after drag&drop

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I would like to gain a effect which update a "state" sql row after dragging element between "DZ", "WT" ,"ZK" divs.

This is how my code looks like.

Sql queries:

```
     $sql = "select * from tasks where login = '$user_check' AND state = 1";
    $sqlDodane = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    
    
    $sql2 = "select * from tasks where login = '$user_check' AND state = 2";
    $sqlWtrakcie = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);
    
    
    $sql3 = "select * from tasks where login = '$user_check' AND state = 3";
    $sqlZakonczone = mysqli_query($db,$sql3);
```

My divs which show rows from database:

```
<div  id ="DZ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
          <?php
    
                    // DIV SHOWING NEW ADDED TASKS (STATE =3)
           echo '<p align = center style=font-size:1vw > <b>Zadania do zrobienia:: </b></p>';
           while($wiersz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlDodane)){
            
                 echo "<div id='zad'  draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>";
                 echo "<p><b>  Zadanie </b> : " .$wiersz['tytul'];
                 echo " <b>Opis </b> : ".$wiersz['opis']."</p>";
                 echo "</div>";
       } 
        ?>
    
           </div>
           <div  id ="WT" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <?php
            // DIV SHOWING CURRENT TASKS (STATE =3)
            echo '<p align = center style=font-size:1vw > <b>Zadania aktualne : </b></p>';
            
             while($wiersz2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlDodane)){
                echo "<div id='zad'  draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' >";
                echo "<p><b>  Zadanie </b> : " .$wiersz2['tytul'];
                echo " <b>Opis </b> : ".$wiersz2['opis']."</p>";
                echo "</div>";
        
           }
                ?>
           </div>
          
           <div  id ="ZK" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
             <?php
             // DIV SHOWING ENDED TASKS (STATE =3) 
            echo '<p align = center style=font-size:1vw > <b>Zadania zakończone  : </b></p>';
            
            while($wiersz3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlDodane)){
                echo "<div id='zad'  draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' >";
                echo "<p><b>  Zadanie </b> : " .$wiersz3['tytul'];
                echo " <b>Opis </b> : ".$wiersz3['opis']."</p>";
                echo "</div>";
           }
                ?>
           </div>
           <?php
```

Javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I am beginner in js and not feel great working in this.
Except that my dragged element sometimes is not positioned corretly i would like to update my "state" column, how to gain this effect?

Comment: You need to send details of the change to the server via an AJAX request (which your Javascript code can generate). You should send it to a specific PHP script whose job is to read that data and update the database appropriately. (The reason to use AJAX is so that you don't have to refresh the whole page just to update one status field).

Answer (score 0):

So now i know that i need to do a ajax request on drop event.
I added to code :
Ajax:

```
function drop(ev, ui) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../update.php',
    data:{data:data},
    success: function(){
        total += parseFloat(data);
        $('#sum').html(total);
    }
});
}
```

And update.php is like this:

```
$tytul = $_POST['tytul'];
$opis = $_POST['opis'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task_id, tytul, opis, state) VALUES ('', '$tytul', '$opis', '$state')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

After all changes its still now working.